# Replacement rule for functions of two variables

Tags: replacement

In Mathematica when I use the substitutions rule (/.) If I have two variables `{NN,H}` each variables has 5 values and i want to substitute about the first variable of `NN` corresponding to the first one of `H` and second one of `NN` corresponding to the second one of `H` .... How can I do that please?

```
nn={10,5,9,20,15}

hh={1,5,3,6,2}
```

I want to substitute about each `n` with it's corresponding `h` in the following equation by the values of `nn` with it's corresponding `hh` from above

```
W=n^2+25(h^3-n*h+2*n^4)-h^2
```

I have tried on it as :

```
Do[Print[W/.{{n->nn[[i]]},{h->hh[[j]]}}],{{i,nn[[1]],nn[[5]],1},{j,hh[[1]],hh[[5]],1}}]
```

Comment: Please include Mathematica code and in order to make the example minimal, reduce the 157 values to maybe 5 values. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, two unrelated things: 1. Instead of `900*10^-9` write `900*^-9` for the scientific form input; 2. Don't use variables starting with an uppercase letter, they are reserved. In particular, `N` is a function defined in the `System\`` namespace, and you got away using it as a variable only because `Table[,,,{x,...}]` implicitly scopes `x` lexically, like `Block[{x},..]`. You'll run into all sorts of amazing errors if you reuse MMA-defined symbols, and it's an open set, changing with versions and namespaces you import with `Need[]` et al. Use e.g. `bigN` instead of `N` for your names.

Comment: That's much better, but please use the same names in both text and code. You have `n`, `N`, `NN`, `h` and `H`. Are `n` and `h` lists? Are they of the same length? Do you want to compute `W` for each pair `n[[i]]` and `h[[i]]` in _parallel_ lists `n` and `h`, or for each possible combination of `n[[i]]` and `h[[j]]`? Please be a little bit more explicit.

Comment: Best of all, write a single code fragment: `nn={....}`, `hh={...}`, `W=...`, `Do[...]`, in 4 lines.

Comment: `W /. Transpose[Thread /@ {n -> nn, h -> hh}]`

Comment: @LouisB: `W /. {n -> nn, h -> hh}` :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start simply:

```
nn = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
hh = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
w = n + 2 h;
```

**1**. The correct iterator syntax for [`Do`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) and other iterating constructs in MMA is `{i, start, end, step}` to evaluate the iterated form for `i` = `start`, `i`  =`start + step`, `i = start + 2 step`, ... until `i <= end` is no longer true. You have *values*, not *indexes* in the iterator; this is a mistake.

Commonly used shorthands for this form of the iterator are:

```
{i, start, end}   is same as     {i, start, end, 1}
{i, end}          is same as     {i, 1, end, 1}
```

Also, two or more iterators are meant to do nested iteration, the second iterating its all values for each value of the first. You can nest as many as required in most constructs. In your approach, you'll get a surprising result of 25 lines printed, not 5, because two iterators define a cross product of their ranges:

```
Do[Print[w /. {n -> nn[[i]], h -> hh[[j]]}], {i, 5}, {j, 5}];

10
12
14
 ... 20 more lines ...
56
58
```

Since your lists are parallel, use just one iterator:

```
Do[Print[w /. {n -> nn[[i]], h -> hh[[i]]}], {i, 5}];

10
22
34
46
58
```

Now the result is as expected.

**2.** Prefer [constructs that return results](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingLists.html#28009) to imperative constructs, like `Do[Print[...]]`. Imperative forms are useful only in narrow circumstances. When using [`Table[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) instead, you can assign its result to a variable and reuse it.

```
In:=   Table[w /. {n -> nn[[i]], h -> hh[[i]]}, {i, 5}]
Out=   {10, 22, 34, 46, 58}
```

You can always `Print[]` it later if you want, once per line or per print cell, depending on a frontend and the stream where Print output is sent:

```
In:=   Table[w /. {n -> nn[[i]], h -> hh[[i]]}, {i, 5}]
Out=   {10, 22, 34, 46, 58}
In:=   Print /@ %
```

(`/@` is an operator form of [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), and the `%` [refers to a last output](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/UsePreviousOutputsInAComputation.html).)

Another nice display construct is [`Column[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Column.html), which puts a column of aligned results into a single output cell:

```
Table[w /. {n -> nn[[i]], h -> hh[[i]]}, {i, 5}] // Column
```

**3.** The most powerful approach is to use the fact that all operators in your expression for `W` are [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html). *Listable* function take lists, operate on each element, and return a list of results. *You do not need any iterating form at all!*

```
In:=  {10, 20} + {1, 2}
Out=  {11, 22}

In:=  w /. {n -> nn, h -> hh}
Out=  {10, 22, 34, 46, 58}
```

MMA applies the expression to each list element. All operators that you are using in the expression assigned to `W`, namely [`Plus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus.html), [`Times`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html) and [`Power`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power.html), are *Listable*.

```
In:=  ww = n^2 + 25 (h^3 - n*h + 2*n^4) - h^2;
      ww /. {n -> nn, h -> hh}
Out=  {500100, 7999924, 40499596, 127999266, 312499084}
```

If in doubt, look at the [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of an expression:

```
In:=  ww // FullForm
Out=  Plus[Times[-1,Power[h,2]],Power[n,2],Times[25,Plus[Power[h,3],Times[-1,h,n],Times[2,Power[n,4]]]]]
```

**4.** [Define functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndPrograms.html#13037).

The ReplaceAll operator ([`/.`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)) may be tricky. A cleaner technique is to make `ww` a function. Functions [lexically scope](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html#30189) their input variables, so there is less room for an error, and fewer global variables. This does the same as **3.** above, but with a function:

```
In:=  ww[n_, h_] := n^2 + 25 (h^3 - n*h + 2*n^4) - h^2;
      ww[nn, hh]

Out=  {500100, 7999924, 40499596, 127999266, 312499084}
```

Neither `n` and `h` "escape" outside, nor they are affected by external definitions of the same variables. Examples of other [scoping constructs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ScopingConstructs.html) are `Table`, `Do`, [`For`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html) and other iteration forms which scope their iterator variables, and [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html), which scopes any symbol you want. Look how the function is unaffected by `n` being defined outside of it:

```
In:=  n = "Strawberry";
      ww[n_, h_] := n^2 + 25 (h^3 - n*h + 2*n^4) - h^2;
      ww[nn, hh]
      n =.

Out=  {500100, 7999924, 40499596, 127999266, 312499084}
```

Comment: @Rabbit thanks much for spotting the typo! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html)?:

e.g.

```
MapThread[#1^2 + 25 (#2^3 - #1*#2 + 2*#1^4) - #2^2 &, {{10, 5, 9, 20, 
   15}, {1, 5, 3, 6, 2}}]
```

yields:

{499874, 33750, 328122, 8002764, 2530921}